# Moving the Up/Down Vote Widget to end of content

Tags: 6, theming, rating

I am brand new to Drupal but not to OOPHP.  I am assuming responsibility for a site which uses [Up/Down Vote](https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) 6.x.

The issue is that the posts are very long and hold many many images and it doesn't look like the module supports any widget position other than at the top of `<div class="content">`.

I would like to move it to just above the footer links of the node, after the content.

I have been googling this without success.  Can anyone advise me or direct me to the relevent docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget is getting displayed using hook_node_view code in vud_node.module...

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_node_view().
 */
function vud_node_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // avoid showing the widget in some node builds
  $exclude_modes = array(
    NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW,
    NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_INDEX,
    NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_RESULT,
    NODE_BUILD_RSS,
  );
  if (in_array($node->build_mode, $exclude_modes)) {
    break;
  }
  if (($can_edit=user_access('use vote up/down on nodes')) || user_access('view vote up/down count on nodes')) {
    $node_type = in_array($node->type, variable_get('vud_node_types', array()), TRUE);
    $widget_showmode = variable_get('vud_node_widget_show', VUD_NODE_DISPLAY_BOTH);
    $tag = variable_get('vud_tag', 'vote');
    $widget = variable_get('vud_node_widget', 'plain');
    $vote_on_teaser = (bool)variable_get('vud_node_widget_vote_on_teaser', TRUE);
    $teaser = $a3;

    $widget_message_code = VUD_WIDGET_MESSAGE_ERROR;
    if (!$can_edit) {
      $widget_message_code = VUD_WIDGET_MESSAGE_DENIED;
    }
    elseif (!$vote_on_teaser) {
      $widget_message_code = VUD_NODE_WIDGET_MESSAGE_TEASER_DENIED;
    }

    if ($node_type) {

      switch ($widget_showmode) {
        case VUD_NODE_DISPLAY_TEASER_ONLY:
          if ($teaser == 1) {
            $node->content['vud_node_widget_display'] = array(
              '#value' => theme('vud_widget', $node->nid, 'node', $tag, $widget, !$vote_on_teaser || !$can_edit, $widget_message_code),
              '#weight' => -10,
            );
          }
          break;
        case VUD_NODE_DISPLAY_FULL_ONLY:
          if ($teaser == 0) {
            $node->content['vud_node_widget_display'] = array(
              '#value' => theme('vud_widget', $node->nid, 'node', $tag, $widget, !$can_edit, $widget_message_code),
              '#weight' => -10,
            );
          }
          break;
        case VUD_NODE_DISPLAY_BOTH:
          if ($teaser == 1) {
            $readonly = !$vote_on_teaser || !$can_edit;
          }
          else {
            $readonly = !$can_edit;
          }
          $node->content['vud_node_widget_display'] = array(
            '#value' => theme('vud_widget', $node->nid, 'node', $tag, $widget, $readonly, $widget_message_code),
            '#weight' => -10,
          );
          break;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Implement [hook_node_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) in your custom module and change the weight to higher value so that it will be displayed at bottom...

In Drupal modules extends permissions by defining them using hook_permission.. You can find list of permissions in "admin/people/permissions" ..

For vote up / down set permissions in above page.. See screenshot below..

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Will do now.  On a separate issue users are reporting that only Admin can see the voting widget.  The config does not have settings pertaining to that.  Any thoughts?  Perhaps I should post as new question.

Comment: See updated answer for permissions issue..

Comment: Thank you very much!  I appreciate your help!  My config does not show this setting.  I have posted a new question with screenshots of config tabs and modules here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110864/vote-up-down-widget-only-visible-to-admins  I sure would appreciate it if you would take a look!

Comment: Turns out I needed to administer user permissions in /admin/users/permissions

Comment: I checked the whole module source for references to vud_node_node_view and did not find any at all.  Is that possibly a 7x change?

Comment: Yeah .. I was referring to 7.x...

Comment: Looks like this is implemented in `vud_node_nodeapi` in vud_node.module in this version