# Vote Up/Down Widget only visible to admins

Tags: 6, rating

I have installed the [Up/Down Vote module](https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) under Drupal 6.x and it is working fine when I use it under my admin login.  However other logged-in users do not see the widget.

Below are screens of the installed modules and all of the config I can access.

What do I do to enable for other users?

[image: config 1]

[image: config 2]

[image: config 3]

[image: modules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the permission for authorized users to be able to vote.

There will be a checkbox you need to tick.

Visit `/admin/user/permissions` and look for permissions relating to this module.

[See this page](https://drupal.org/getting-started/6/admin/user/permissions) for more help.

Comment: You rock!  It's folks like you who make StackOverflow so indispensable!  Thank you!